# Equation of sphere through points $(1,1,2)$ and $(2,-2,3)$ with center on $2x+3y=0=5x+y-z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, spheres

I'm having trouble finding the values of $u$, $v$ and $w$ through solving the equations by substituting the given points in $x^2+y^2+z^2+2ux+2vy+2wz+d=0$.

The answer given is $2(x^2+y^2+z^2)- 3x + 2y -13z + 15 = 0$ and my answer is nowhere close.

Edit: Perhaps it may be either the equation is wrong or the answer is. I believe it more likely to be an incorrect answer.

Comment: Are you sure of the second equation for the line? According to the answer, the center should be $(3/4,-1/2,-13/4),$ which does not satisfy $5x+y-z=0.$

Comment: Perhaps it is the given answer that is wrong. Both the equation and answer are written (typed) in our notes but the questions are compiled from many different books while the answer is inserted by our professor (TA probably). I've found wrong answers for other questions as well, so there's precedent.

Comment: Apply the distance formula on the two given points from the centre $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$. Note that the quadratic terms cancel out when you equate them. This should give a linear equation in terms of $x_i$, $y_i$, $z_i$. The point $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ satisfies the 2 equations given in the questions, thus you have a system of 3 equations for 3 variables, which is easily solvable. Thus, the equation of the sphere is given by:
$(x - x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2+(z-z_i)^2 = r^2$, where $r$ is the distance of $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ from either of the given points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the line of intersection between

$2 x + 3y = 0$

$5x + y - z = 0 $

The point $(0,0,0)$ is an obvious solution.

The direction vector of the line is

$V = (2, 3, 0) \times (5, 1, -1) = (-3, 2, -13) $

So the line is $\ell(t) = t (-3, 2, -13)$

So now have

$ R^2 = (1 + 3 t)^2 + (1 - 2 t)^2 + (2 + 13 t)^2 = (2 + 3 t)^2 + (-2 - 2 t)^2 + (3 + 13 t)^2$

Therefore,

$1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + t (6 - 4 + 52) = 2^2 + (-2)^2 + 3^2 + t (12 + 8 + 78)$

So that

$ t (44) = - 11 $

and $ t = -\dfrac{1}{4} $

Therefore, the center is

$ C = -\dfrac{1}{4} (-3, 2, -13) = ( \dfrac{3}{4}, - \dfrac{1}{2} , \dfrac{13}{4} ) $

and

$ R^2 = (\dfrac{1}{4})^2 + (\dfrac{3}{2})^2 + (\dfrac{5}{4})^2 = \dfrac{62}{16} $

And the equation of the sphere is

$ (x - \dfrac{3}{4})^2 + (y + \dfrac{1}{2} )^2 + ( z - \dfrac{13}{4})^2 = \dfrac{62}{16} $

Multiplying through by $16$

$ (4 x - 3 )^2 + (4 y + 2 )^2 + (4 z - 13)^2 = 62 $

Expanding

$ 16 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - 24 x + 16 y - 104 z + 9 + 4 + 169 = 62 $

And finally,

$ 16 x^2 + 16 y^2 + 16 z^2 - 24 x + 16 y - 104 z + 120 = 0 $

Dividing through by $8$

$ 2 x^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 z^2 - 3 x + 2 y - 13z + 15 = 0 $